# Should I create a POST version of my GET REST endpoint in case the GET URI is too long?

Tags: rest, post, get, http-post, api-design

I have a REST endpoint `GET /api/rules`. It takes several query parameters for filtering/querying, like `type`, `name`, `owner`, `description`, and `tag`. So you could end up with a URI like this:

`GET /api/rules?name=rule1,rule2&owner=john,jane&description=VeryLongDescription`

Specifically, I'm concerned that the description queried for could be very long and make the URI too long (I forget the limit). Should I create a POST version of this same endpoint for users that get a `414 URI Too Long` response from the server?

I mean, generally speaking, when does it make sense to just make a POST that gets a resource? Anytime you introduce query params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory URIs have no limits, but in practice they might be limited by implementations. If you have to circumvent limitations imposed by the implementation that are not inherent to the protocol, you should try to decouple them from your application.

If you're a purist, the more or less standard way of supporting functionality through the POST method is using the `x-http-method-override` header, which can be decoupled from your application if it's implemented as a request pre-processor. You can have the preprocessor convert the POST request to the GET request your application expects, converting the payload to a query string.

Here's an example of this approach in the Google Translate API: https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#Translate

If you're not a purist, or if that's too complicated for your users, or you don't want to use a custom header, I think it's fine to make a POST endpoint that gets a resource, as long as it's properly documented and the resource being queried is identified by the URI.